# Find index in array of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I would like to find index in array. Positions in array are objects, and I want to filter on their properties. I know which keys I want to filter and their values. Problem is to get index of array which meets the criteria.

For now I made code to filter data and gives me back object data, but not index of array.

```
var data =  [
        {
            "text":"one","siteid":"1","chid":"default","userid":"8","time":1374156747
        },
        {
            "text":"two","siteid":"1","chid":"default","userid":"7","time":1374156735
        }
    ];

var filterparams = {userid:'7', chid: 'default'};

function getIndexOfArray(thelist, props){
    var pnames = _.keys(props)
    return _.find(thelist, function(obj){
        return _.all(pnames, function(pname){return obj[pname] == props[pname]})
    })};

var check = getIndexOfArray(data, filterparams ); // Want to get '2', not key => val
```

Comment: not really an answer but you could have used `_.findWhere` to get exactly the same result as what you have now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/fkEV7/) is thefiddle hope it helps you

```
 for(var intIndex=0;intIndex < data.length; intIndex++){
  eachobj = data[intIndex];
var flag = true;
 for (var k in filterparams) {

    if (eachobj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        if(eachobj[k].toString() != filterparams[k].toString()){
           flag = false;
        }
    }
}
if(flag){
       alert(intIndex);
}
```

}

Answer (score 11):

Using [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com) in place of underscore you can do it pretty easily with [`_.findIndex()`](http://lodash.com/docs#findIndex).

```
var index = _.findIndex(array, { userid: '7', chid: 'default' })
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I think that this is what you need:

```
var data =  [{
    "text":"one","siteid":"1","chid":"default","userid":"8","time":1374156747
}, {
    "text":"two","siteid":"1","chid":"default","userid":"7","time":1374156735
}];
var filterparams = {userid:'7', chid: 'default'};

var index = data.indexOf( _.findWhere( data, filterparams ) );
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it IS using underscore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need underscore for that just regular ole js - hope this is what you are looking for

```
var data =  [
        {
            "text":"one","siteid":"1","chid":"default","userid":"8","time":1374156747
        },
        {
            "text":"two","siteid":"1","chid":"default","userid":"7","time":1374156735
        }
    ];

var userid = "userid"
var filterparams = {userid:'7', chid: 'default'};
var index;
for (i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (prop in data[i]) {
        if ((prop === userid) && (data[i]['userid'] === filterparams.userid)) {
            index = i
        }
    }
}

alert(index);
```

Comment: I think he wants an `indexOf` not a `lastIndexOf`…

Comment: What's that `prop === userid` thing supposed to do there? Can't you omit the property enumeration of `data[i]` then entirely?

Comment: prop === userid has to equal the object's key value which I just stored in a variable